# How to use std::find in a loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to fill a vector named firstApp with some informations(id,position(x,y),frameNumber).So I make a condition to avoid filling the vector with existing informations.

```
std::vector<FirstAppearance>::iterator p;
for (int idxCurrent = 0; idxCurrent < nOfPedcurrFrame ;  idxCurrent++) 
{


            if(nOfPedprevFrame == 0)
            {
                CurrentId=frames[frameNumber].GetPedest()[idxCurrent].GetID();  

                FA=FirstAppear(frames,CurrentId,idxCurrent);

                 FirstPosition=frames[FA].GetPedest()[idxCurrent].GetPosition();

                f.SetFrameNumber(FA);
                f.SetFirstPosition(FirstPosition);
                f.SetFId(CurrentId);


                if(firstApp.size() !=0 )
                {


                    p=std::find(firstApp.begin(),firstApp.end(),f);
                    std::cout << *p<< endl;


                    if(p == firstApp.end())
                    {
                        firstApp.push_back(f);

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    firstApp.push_back(f);

                }


                f.~FirstAppearance();
             }
}
```

FirstAppearnce.cpp:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "FirstAppearance.h"
 #include <iostream>

FirstAppearance::FirstAppearance(){}
int FirstAppearance::GetFId(void)const {return fId;}
objectCoordinates FirstAppearance::GetFirstPosition(void)const {return firstPosition;}
void FirstAppearance::SetFirstPosition(objectCoordinates pos){firstPosition =pos;}
void FirstAppearance::SetFId(int id){fId =id;}
int FirstAppearance::GetFrameNumber(void)const {return fNumber;}
void FirstAppearance::SetFrameNumber(int fnumb){ fNumber = fnumb;}
bool FirstAppearance::operator==(const FirstAppearance& a){

    if((firstPosition.x == a.firstPosition.x) && (firstPosition.y == a.firstPosition.y) &&
    (fId==a.fId) && (fNumber==a.fNumber)){
        return true;        
    }
}
FirstAppearance::~FirstAppearance(){}
```

I use std::find to search if f exists in my vector to fill it on.But when I compile my program I got that p had such value the first value of f along the life of my program.Can any one tell me why std::find didn't update the value of f with the new value??
the output of *p is:

```
1 263 138 0
1 263 138 0
1 263 138 0
1 263 138 0
1 263 138 0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to fix your code formatting.

Comment: `f.~FirstAppearance();` looks suspicious

Comment: Dereferencing `p` when `p==firstApp.end()` is undefined behavior. A smart compiler will then optimize out the `if(p == firstApp.end())` check and always do `firstApp.push_back(f);`. Also `f.~FirstAppearance();` most definitely doesn't do what you meant to do.

Comment: Like @nwp implied: using `std::find()` on an empty vector will return `std::vector<T>::end`, which leads to _undefined_ behavior when dereferenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool FirstAppearance::operator==(const FirstAppearance& a)
{

if((firstPosition.x == a.firstPosition.x) && (firstPosition.y == a.firstPosition.y) &&
(fId==a.fId) && (fNumber==a.fNumber)){
    return true;        
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the result correctly.
You should have something like :

```
p=std::find(firstApp.begin(),firstApp.end(),f);
if (p == firstApp.end()) {
  std::cout << f << " not found." << endl;
  firstApp.push_back(f);
} else {
  std::cout << *p << endl;    
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems that it test always with the first value of and enter to the else instruction and display as usually the same result: 1 263 138 0